# The best hyperlink relation to the source of the post

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, search-engine

I would like to post some article from other blogs and I will add the url of the original post. What is the best rel="" type for the hyperlinks? Is rel="bookmark" will SEO friendly? I need Googles bles and want to tell that my article is the same as the original, but in different platform and environment.

Comment: “my article is the same as the original, but in different platform and environment” — I’m confused. If you’re literally just reposting articles from other blogs on your own website, how is your “platform and environment” different to the original website? You’re just another website, surely? How come you’re copying other people’s content?

Comment: I will not just reposting the entire article, but add notes and tips for some parts of them. I just want to use something more sophisticated than a simple dofollow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `rel` attribute that will help your seo or the seo of the other site. Just the regular link without `nofollow` is the best thing you can do.